# Comparing two pointer arrays

Tags: c, sorting, pointers

So the question was to sort one array by two different pointers whose addresses are similar and then compare the sorted arrays to see if they are similar. Now I've got through with the first part but for the life of me I'm not able to figure out how I'm supposed to compare them and print if they are similar or not. (And no I cannot use malloc anywhere)

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sort(int *ptr1){
  int i,j,k;
  for (i=0;i<8;i++){
    for (j=i+1;j<8;j++){
      if (*(ptr1+j)<*(ptr1+i)){
        k=*(ptr1+i);
        *(ptr1+i)=*(ptr1+j);
        *(ptr1+j)=k;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("\nSorted array: ");
  for (i=0;i<8;i++){
    printf("%d, ",*(ptr1+i));
  }
}
int main()
{
int a[8],i;
int arr[8] = {41, 56, 23, 78, 12, 7, 243, 23};
printf("Original array: ");
for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
     printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
  }
int *ptr1 = arr;
int **ptr2 = &ptr1;
printf("\nThe Address of ptr1: %p\nThe Address of ptr2: %p\n", *ptr1,**ptr2);
sort(ptr1);
sort(*ptr2);  

return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Original array: 41, 56, 23, 78, 12, 7, 243, 23, 
The Address of ptr1: 0x29
The Address of ptr2: 0x29

Sorted array: 7, 12, 23, 23, 41, 56, 78, 243, 
Sorted array: 7, 12, 23, 23, 41, 56, 78, 243,
```

Comment: I don't understand what's the purpose of sorting the same array using 2 different pointers. The end result will be same regardless.

Comment: The second pointer is basically pointing to the first one

Comment: yes i know that... its for reviewing concepts basically but i don't know the code to compare them anyway

Comment: also the sorted arrays are coming out different

Comment: For the second sorted array, those are garbage values. You need to double dereference the second pointer to get the actual array value.

Comment: how do you do that??

Comment: Just replace `sort(ptr2)` with `sort(*ptr2)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243737/discussion-between-light-and-nezuko).